# How to find and log the longest repeating serie of numbers in array with javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

My problem is I can't console.log the repeating after another same numbers in the array. I can find which number how many times appears with this code:

```
var array = [2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1],
    currentNum = 1,
    counter = 0,
    item;

for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    for (var j = i; j < array.length; j++) {
        if (array[i] == array[j])
            counter++;
        if (currentNum < counter) {
            currentNum = counter;
            item = array[i];
        }
    }
    counter = 0;
}
console.log(item + " ( " + currentNum + " times ) ");
```

But my real issue is that I want to log the **2, 2, 2** part and I don't know how.
Thank you guys very much in advance!

Comment: what should happen if two numbers have the same repeating count?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following will find the first instance of longest (assuming more than one same length sequence)

The first `reduce()` creates subarrays for each sequence, the second reduce() checks lengths of those sub arrays returning the first instance of longest sequence

```js
var array = [2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1];

var res = array.reduce(function(a,c,i){
  if(a.length && a[a.length-1][0] ===c){
     a[a.length-1].push(c)
  }else{
    a.push([c]);
  }  
  return a
},[]).reduce(function(a,c){
  return c.length > a.length ? c : a;
});

console.log('Sequence length=',res.length);
console.log('Value=', res[0]);
```

If you expect multiple same length sequences and want to capture all the values that match can modify second reduce  something like:

```js
var array = [2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 7, 7, 7];

var res = array.reduce(function(a,c,i){
  if(a.length && a[a.length-1][0] ===c){
     a[a.length-1].push(c)
  }else{
    a.push([c]);
  }  
  return a
},[]).reduce(function(a,c){
  if(c.length > a.len){
    // reset when longer sequence found
    a.values = [c[0]];
    a.len = c.length;
  } else if(c.length === a.len){
    // add new value when same length found
    a.values.push(c[0]);
  }
  return a
},{len:0,values:[]});


console.log('Sequence length=', res.len)
console.log('How many times=', res.values.length)
console.log('Values = ', res.values.join()  )
```

Comment: Thank you very much :)))

Comment: what is the complexity of this algorithm?

Answer (score 0):

Array.prototype.forEach or reduce is better for iteration through an array.
Here is a solution with a single going through array (just 3 additional variables :) )

```
var array = [2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1]

var item = array[0], maxTimes = 1, currentTimes = 1

array.reduce(function(prev, current) {
 if (prev === current) {
   currentTimes = currentTimes + 1

   if (currentTimes > maxTimes) {
     maxTimes = currentTimes
     item = current
   }
 } else {
   currentTimes = 1
 }

 return current
})

console.log(item, maxTimes)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) with an object which holds the temporary result and the actual count of the item.

If an item is equal to the last item, last count is incremented and checked if the count is greater than the temporary count. Then the temporary count is replaced by the actual count.

```js
var array = [2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1],
    count = array.reduce(function (r, a, i, aa) {
        if (a === aa[i - 1]) {
            r.last.count++;
            if (!(r.last.count <= r.result.count)) {
                r.result = r.last;
            }
        } else {
            r.last = { value: a, count: 1 };
        }
        return r;
    }, { last: {}, result: {} }).result;

console.log(count);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```